# How to align two html tables with same headers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two html tables, first one is two rows 1 for headers and one for buttons to hide columns in table 2.

```
    <table id="buttons" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Header 1</td>
                <td>Header 2</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 3</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 4</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 5</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 6</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 7</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 8</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 9</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 10</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 11</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 12</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 13</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 14</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 15</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 16</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 17</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 18</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 19</strong></td>
                <td>Header 20</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><strong>Header 21</strong></td>
                <td>Header 22</td>
                <td>Header 23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>

                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(2);" class="">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(3);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(4);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(5);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(6);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(7);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(8);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(9);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(10);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(11);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(12);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(13);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(14);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(15);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(16);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(17);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>


                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(18);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>

                <td></td>

                <td style="text-align:center">

                    <label>

                        <input type="checkbox" checked="" onchange="javascript:show_hide_column(20);">

                        <span class="slider round"></span>

                    </label>
                </td>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="relative-table wrapped confluenceTable" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 1</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 2</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff" style=""><strong>Header
                        3</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 4</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 5</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 6</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 7</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 8</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 9</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 10</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 11</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 12</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 13</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 14</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 15</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 16</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 17</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 18</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 19</strong>
                </td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 20</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 21</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 22</strong></td>
                <td class="highlight-#b3d4ff confluenceTd" title="Background color : Light blue 100%"
                    data-highlight-colour="#b3d4ff"><strong>Header 23</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>89</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>89</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This_is_a_very_long_text_to_display_what_my_real_table_looks_like</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>78</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>89</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is what it looks like
[image: output_of_html_code]

I want the columns to align with each other so each column in table 1 is equal to its respective column in table 2
I tried setting column groups to be equal to each other using the following JS code:

```
document.getElementById('buttons').style.width = document.getElementsByClassName('relative-table wrapped confluenceTable')[0].style.width
    colgroup = document.getElementsByClassName('relative-table wrapped confluenceTable')[0].getElementsByTagName('colgroup')[0]   
    document.getElementById('buttons').getElementsByTagName('colgroup')[0].innerHTML = colgroup.innerHTML
```

yet no luck.

I also hard coded the column groups, using both pixels and percentages, into both tables and still no luck:

```
     <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 8.10965%;">
            <col style="width: 4.71625%;">
            <col style="width: 2.70322%;">
            <col style="width: 2.70322%;">
            <col style="width: 2.93328%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.04831%;">
            <col style="width: 3.27837%;">
            <col style="width: 3.3934%;">
            <col style="width: 3.3934%;">
            <col style="width: 3.22085%;">
            <col style="width: 3.16334%;">
            <col style="width: 4.1411%;">
            <col style="width: 7.24692%;">
            <col style="width: 14.7814%;">
            <col style="width: 5.11886%;">
            <col style="width: 8.22468%;">
        </colgroup>
```

How can I do this using vanilla html, css and js?
Note: the second table is a confluence page

Comment: @GiovannaPennaEirada joining the table will prevent unhiding the columns, `table-layout: fixed;`  doesn't extend the cell to fit the text, so the text bleeds into other cells in the table even when width is set to 100%
BTW, `display-table: fixed` does not appear to be a valid attribute

Comment: My bad, the correct attribute is `table-layout: fixed`.

Comment: @GiovannaPennaEirada it still overflows to the next cells